# Best way to find the pre-defined schema properties in a json file

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema

I have a json schema file which follows the custom rules I've created. This schema file is a valid json file. It follows the below pattern.

```
 {
    "name":   {
                "fname" :  {
                             "displayName":"FirstName",
                             "dataType":"String"
                           }
                "lname"  : {
                             "displayName":"LastName",
                             "dataType":"String"
                           }
               },
    "address": {
                   "displayName":"Address",
                   "dataType":"String"
               }
  }
```

so based on the schema I need to create the below json with respective values.

```
  {
       "name": {
                 "FirstName": "test",
                 "LastName" : "test1"
               },
       "Address" : "someAddress"
  }
```

So when I get the schema, what is the best way to find the config information node? That is the leaf node which has the displayName and dataType parameters. Currently I'm traversing this tree using Jackson json and finding the nodes with displayName and dataType keys. Because I cannot precisely say at which level this leaf node could be present. Is there a better way to handle this situation than traversing the whole json tree looking for the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not sure wnat exactly is required (do you want the `fname` object or the value of its properties), however, [`JsonPath`](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) seems like a good fit here.  It is the equivalent of xpath for json - search hierarchy model based on various criteria

I made a small demo to get you started. you just need to twaek the query string to suit your requirements. You can use the [Jayway JsonPath Evaluator](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/) as REPL

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.*;
public class JsonPathDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // query: get all json objects that have displayName and dataType properties
        String jsonPathQuery = "$..*[?(@.displayName && @.dataType)]";
        try {
            String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C://temp/xx.json")));
            Object parsedContent = Configuration.defaultConfiguration().jsonProvider().parse(content);
            Object configElements = JsonPath.read(parsedContent, jsonPathQuery);
            System.out.println(configElements.getClass());
            System.out.println(configElements);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

output is

```
class net.minidev.json.JSONArray
[{"displayName":"Address","dataType":"String"},{"displayName":"FirstName","dataType":"String"},{"displayName":"LastName","dataType":"String"}]
```

**EDIT:** answer for question in comment:

It is possible to check for path existence (and make all sorts of other assertions) using [json-path-assert](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath/tree/master/json-path-assert):

```
import static com.jayway.jsonpath.matchers.JsonPathMatchers.*;

// query for specific path 
String jsonSpecificPathQuery = "$..name.fname.displayName";

String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C://temp/xx.json")));
Object parsedContent = Configuration.defaultConfiguration().jsonProvider().parse(content);
System.out.println("hasJsonPath? " + hasJsonPath(jsonSpecificPathQuery).matches(parsedContent));
```

Comment: Is there a way to check if the path exists in a key's value instead of reading it into configElements object?

Comment: I assumed that `JsonPath` would have a similar `check()` method to `read()` so I went to jayway github root in search for the source, and the assert directory caught my eye. I guess I was lucky :)